# Coverture of a method ASM Java

Tags: java, code-coverage, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

Hello and thank you in advance for your answers. I would like to know if there is any way to know (using ASM) which lines I've gone through and which ones I haven't on real time. In other words, a way in which, as soon as any method has finished executing, for each execution, I can inject an instrumentation instruction for it to print which lines it has or hasn't gone through

Comment: One possible solution could involve injecting wait/notify pairs between each line that report the current "step" and effectively pause execution.

Comment: @Vulcan or just perform the “report the current step” part without the other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create a class with a static method that logs the line number execution events. It would have a method like this:

```
public static void lineExecution(String filename, int lineNumber)
```

Put whatever logic you need. Capture the event in-memory and report at the end, or just write it to stdout.

When you are modifying the target classes with ASM, you need to decorate the `visitSource` method in `ClassVisitor`.

This method should capture the "source" parameter (the source file) for use later. Then, you need to return a custom MethodVisitor from `visitMethod` with a decorated `visitLineNumber` method. This method should insert a call to your static method:

```
ldc (whatever the value of "source" is)
ldc (whatever line number was passed in)
invokestatic LineExecutionMonitor.lineExecution
```

Thus, whenever a new line number is executed, the first thing that happens it that a call is made to your static method. There you can trace execution within the instrumented class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I could do it, thank you so much for your help ^^
When I'll have enought reputation I'll vote you positive your answer.